Code Runner creates .class files along with the .java files in my src folder rather than bin (VS Code)
It works fine when I run it through the Java Extension Pack, though I would much prefer to use Code Runner for all my projects in all languages if that is at all possible. If anyone can help me I will be eternally grateful.
I have tried various solutions offered in other Stack Overflow questions of this same nature, including:

Editing settings.json to include { "java.project.outputPath" = "bin" }
Editing code-runner.executorMap
Creating a tasks.json file with the relevant commands and running build task
Creating a compile.bat file with the relevant commands
Cleaning the Java language server workspace
Configuring the classpath
Rebuilding the project both manually and with Maven
Installing the latest version of JDK
Ensuring JAVA_HOME is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-22
Editing the PATH variable to include the bin directory


Go to line 136 of ~/.vscode/extensions/formulahendry.code-runner-0.12.2/package.json and change it to "java": "cd $dir && javac -d bin $fileName && java -cp bin $fileNameWithoutExt",

@g00se Wow, this is the best solution I've seen so far. Thank you. However, when I run my project it creates the bin folder inside the src folder rather than in the project directory itself. Is this expected or is there a solution to this as well?

Try, in that case, -d ../bin and -cp ../bin. But really you should use a build tool such as Maven or Gradle as the first point of control as that solution won't really scale well

@g00se It works perfectly now, I can't thank you enough. I'll be sure to use Maven in future

That's good. You can try to create a Maven project and move your code into it
